# Don't ban users who are improving

Tags: discussion, feature-request, banning

I am proposing that the SO question ban algorithm lets users who are improving their question score ask one more question.

I was banned from Stack Overflow for asking bad questions. I began to improve (slowly). I was still banned even when I was improving. I am unbanned now. I got to ask that one more question, because I was serially upvoted. The serial upvotes where reversed and my new question was upvoted. Yes, I know I was stupid before and should have read more help documents and...

[image: My improvement]

Trendline: y = 0.79 x - 5.7

The line of best fit clearly shows that I was getting better at asking questions over time, yet I was still banned. I received an upvote which unbanned me.

I believe that the question banning algorithm should take into account if a user is improving over time. Users that are improving are likely to continue to improve. Users who do not show signs of improvement should still be banned. This should only unban a user if they are on the edge. Users who improve from -20 to -10 should not be unbanned just because they improved. Users who are improving in a near of the ban threshold should be allowed to ask one more question.

I'm not suggesting that the question ban algorithm should be completely redone, but tweak slightly.

I am not banned.

Comment: Maybe because you weren't improving fast enough.  Not saying this is true of your case, but going from terrible to bad still isn't good enough.

Comment: @ryanyuyu In my option users who improve from terible to bad are likely to improve from bad to okay and then from okay to good. But I could be wrong. Anyone know how to run a query for that?

Comment: Oh I agree with that.  But at some point it's still not good enough.

Comment: Given that there are people who do in fact get out of bans because they have improved, the algorithm *already* does take improvements into account. I cannot tell what exactly is the major factor in your case but judging by your graph here and what I can see in your profile, you do have at least one question with negative score that was deleted. The advice I keep hearing for people who are banned is "improve your bad posts rather than delete them". So maybe there's that? (One thing for sure, deletion does not hide a post from the ban algorithm.)

Comment: We don't know the algorithm but it probably takes into account the number of up votes and down votes, not just the net score. A question with 2 up votes is probably better than a question with 4 up votes and 1 down vote. That's just a guess though.

Comment: @Louis My bad posts were beyond repair. They could not be fixed without completely changing the question.

Comment: @2426021684 Ok, then they were unsalvageable. This means you'll have work more to get out of the ban than if those posts were salvageable.

Comment: Isn't there SOME way to flag a post for moderation and ask about it being disassociated from you?

Comment: @Louis Unsalvageable posts are not necessarly worse than salvageable posts. They are just bad in different ways.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Some people are slow learners.

Comment: @2426021684 it's a shame for those users, but the site has a quality standard, there is a point where there is enough "damage" done to the site that enough is enough.

Comment: @Patrice I'm not saying we should let users ask 10 more questions before they get banned. I'm talking about 1 or 2 if they have been improving. People are just going to create a new account anyway.

Comment: @2426021684 I am not speaking to your specific issue here, I am just talking about the generic statement you made. In any case, "creating new accounts" isn't as effective as you'd think...

Comment: @Patrice I'm pretty sure SO can't bypass TOR. Also getting a new IP from your ISP is not that difficult.

Comment: That's a pretty weak fit...

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it is but there still is definently a correlation

Comment: @2426021684 have fun. If that's how you see the quality restrictions of the site and go around them, I can foresee your new account will get a similar treatment to this one. There is a reason the systems we have are in place. Bypassing them shows a disregard for this community and its guidelines that is likely to transpire through your questions...

Comment: @Patrice I was unbanned before I asked this question and still am. I am not going to make a new account. I now know how to ask good questions. I just learned too slow and asked hard to repair questions. I wanted to make it easer for the next person like me.

Comment: How come after asking this I recieved downvotes on 2 questions that in my opinion are good? One of them was even +2. No comment either. I can't fix them if you don't tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Goodbye. Since people are saying that I hurt this site I have decided to leave. I would like to thank the couple of people that look the time to help me.

Comment: I agree that this is not a good idea. But I learn from this question that I need to read more carefully about Stack Overflow's guidelines. Beside, I still think this is a good "down-voted" question (the question is not bad but the downvoted is really make me laugh)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea.

"improvement" is inherently subjective. Going from "very very bad" to "very bad" is an improvement, but I still wouldn't want that user to continue "contributing" to the site.

It's been a while since I was a new user, and I can say that I've seen a *lot* of new resources geared toward onboarding new users that didn't exist when I started. I have a hard time excusing such behavior when we now have an extensive FAQ and help pages.

The fact of the matter is you were question banned because you were asking poor quality questions. There are a number of signals that you should have noticed before ever getting close to a question ban.

The first of which would be downvotes. If you're receiving a lot of downvotes, it's *your* job to figure out why, and to correct your post.

The second would be close votes. If a question you've asked gets put on hold, it's *your* job to figure out why and to be sure you don't make that mistake again.

Question banning only happens when a user shows that they're consistently unable to follow [Stack Overflow's guidelines](/help/how-to-ask).

Instead of attempting to make excuses for why you were banned and should not have been, consider spending some time away from Stack Overflow reflecting on the actions you took to put yourself in this position.

It's rough. No one likes being sidelined, but sometimes it's necessary.

Comment: Sometimes correcting your posts can be impossible. I could not care less what the question ban is now. I am unbanned and now know how to ask good questions. I just was hoping that the next person in my position would have an easiser time. I was given another chance when someone serially upvoted me. I was able to ask another question (which was upvoted) before the system reversed the votes. If it was not for that person, I would still be banned.

Comment: On the "it is your job" sentences. The only reason why I learned how to ask good questions is because of people helping me in the comments. If not for them I would still be banned.

Comment: @2426021684, [just because you can't ask doesn't mean you can't contribute](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/153542). Additionally, given the number of questions you asked, I find it hard to believe you couldn't find anything else to improve with them. Remember, edits to questions will cause the question to be visible on the homepage again. But as I said in my answer: spend some time reflecting on how you got here. Ask yourself: Did you really need to ask the questions you did that got negative scores? Are you able to research more before asking? Can you get help composing your questions?

Comment: I know I was stupid before. I understand why my questions are terrible. They were off-topic/duplicates/subjective/requests for libraries. I can't fix them without completely changing the question. I just learned too slowly.

Comment: Where would a new user get help composing questions?

Comment: help center has a TON of articles. There are a lot of information on meta, and a bunch of blog's posts about how to properly ask SO questions.

Comment: @2426021684, at any time before your question ban you could have asked a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) asking for help on how to properly ask questions. What concerns me is that you're asking me these questions directly even now without having used google to search and then rephrase and search again (search-again: research). It's why I recommend you spend some time being introspective.

Comment: @zzzzBov To be fair, I think that SO was a bit more lax earlier on. I see plenty of old stuff that's still around, but would be down voted on site if posted today.

Comment: ""improvement" is inherently subjective" - do you mean relative, not subjective?

Answer (score 9):

"Improving" is the operative word.  In my mind, you should *keep* improving until your questions have a net positive score.

To that point, I feel like the question ban is acceptable; you need to work on the questions which weren't well received until they can are received better.

Looking at your data points, you have a total net question score of -2.  This is because the questions which were not as well received *before* are greatly weighing down the questions which *were* received positively.

The best thing you can do in all realism is to go back and improve your *existing* questions as best as you can, where you can.  The questions scored -9 and -5 are especially detrimental to you so I would put more energy into those.